# Java Parse Date w/ SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, jakarta-mail, simpledateformat

I'm sure this is a simple one!
I've got this String `String date = "Wed, 2 Jan 2013 12:17:15 +0000 (GMT)"` which I want to parse to a Date to be able to set an JavaMail's sent date.

Here's my full code

```
String dateString = "Wed, 2 Jan 2013 12:17:15 +0000 (GMT)";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
System.out.println("Date: " + date.toString());
email.setSentDate(oDate); // Assume email is initialised correctly
```

Expected output

```
Date: Wed, 2 Jan 2013 12:17:15 +0000 (GMT)
```

Actual output

```
Date: Wed Jan 02 12:17:15 GMT 2013
```

I'm not even bothered about the time component, as long as my email appears to be from the correct date.

Comment: Your pattern worked pretty well for parsing dates of emails from Gmail's API. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String reformattedStr = sdf.format(sdf.parse(dateString));
```

or this

```
String reformattedStr = sdf.format(sdf.parse(date.toString()));
```

Comment: Yup, that's it. I suppose the question now is, why isn't the Javamail liking that format?

Answer (score 0):

[Date.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) applies its own format when converting to string:

```
Converts this Date object to a String of the form:

     dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
```

You should use `DateFormat` to get a desired string, ie for a posted code example:

```
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

The setSentDate method will format the date properly for an email message before setting it in the email message.  That's different than what Date.toString() does.  See also the [MailDateFormat](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MailDateFormat.html) class.